# Recursive SQL Query for 6 individual months of following query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering if there is a way to perform the following query recursively so it does so 6 times for the most recent 6 months.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS 'Month', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Low',
       SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 2 THEN 1 END) AS 'Med',
       SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 3 THEN 1 END) AS 'High'
FROM dbo.ChangeEvaluationForm
WHERE MONTH(DateSubmitted) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

The results for this query are as follows

[image]

I'd like to return 5 more rows with data for each of the months prior to the current month.  Is that something that's possible?  I'd like to avoid performing 5 more individual queries if I can.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: what happens when you remove the where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `GROUP BY` and using `DATEADD()` to move back 6 months from the current month:

```
Select   DateName(Month, DateSubmitted) As 'Month', 
         Sum(Case When OverallRiskRating = 1 Then 1 End) As 'Low',
         Sum(Case When OverallRiskRating = 2 Then 1 End) As 'Med',
         Sum(Case When OverallRiskRating = 3 Then 1 End) As 'High'
From     dbo.ChangeEvaluationForm
Where    DateSubmitted >= DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, DateAdd(Month, -6, GetDate())), 0)
Group By DateName(Month, DateSubmitted)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursive cte

```
declare @Date smalldatetime
set @Date = '20170801'

;with cte as 
(
    select @Date as StartMonth

    union all

    select DATEADD(MONTH, -1, StartMonth)
    from cte
    where StartMonth > DATEADD(MONTH, -5, @Date)
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, D) AS 'Month', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Low',
       SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 2 THEN 1 END) AS 'Med',
       SUM(CASE WHEN OverallRiskRating = 3 THEN 1 END) AS 'High'
FROM dbo.ChangeEvaluationForm
    inner join cte on MONTH(DateSubmitted) = MONTH(StartMonth)
```

Comment: I don't need. Topicstarter wants to use recursive call.

Comment: I'll take blame for that, I thought recursion was going to be necessary and that is what I asked for.